# value in object that is stored in AsyncStorage is not incrementing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, firebase-storage

I am using AsyncStorage to store an object that will be used to determine when to show the rating library. All I am trying to do is increment the Rating_Count key  +1 each time the function is called. In the code below the else statement keeps running even after the first time the function is called.
The console.log(TEST) shows the value of RATING_COUNT to be 0.
If I then change the if conditional to be testStorage1 !== null,
the console.log(OH NO) has Rating_count: NaN, but the console.log(TEST) shows the Rating_count to be 0.

```js
  const testFunction = async () => {

    var testStorage1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem( IN_APP_RATING_COUNT )
    testStorage1 = JSON.parse( testStorage1 );
    console.log('TEST',testStorage1);
    
    const testObject = { 
      Rating_count: testStorage1.Rating_count <-- Added the .Rating_count,
      Rating_date: new Date()
    };
   await AsyncStorage.setItem(IN_APP_RATING_COUNT, JSON.stringify(testObject));

    if(testStorage1.Rating_count >= 0) {

      AsyncStorage.getItem( IN_APP_RATING_COUNT )
      .then((testStorage) => {
  
        testStorage = JSON.parse( testStorage );
        testStorage.Rating_count++;
        AsyncStorage.setItem( IN_APP_RATING_COUNT, JSON.stringify( testStorage ) );
        console.log('OH NO!',testStorage);
        
      })
      .catch((error) => {console.log(error)});

       

    } else {

      AsyncStorage.getItem( IN_APP_RATING_COUNT )
    .then((testStorage) => {

      testStorage = JSON.parse( testStorage );
      testStorage.Rating_count = 0;
      AsyncStorage.setItem( IN_APP_RATING_COUNT, JSON.stringify( testStorage ) );
      console.log('YESS',testStorage);

    })
    .catch((error) => {console.log(error)});
     
    }
     

  }
```

Comment: Can you try making the then functions async and then your AsyncStorage.setItems lines with keyword 'await' ?

Comment: Nope that didnt work. The else still ran '0' is getting saved, and the if is running, but it has to do with something in the main if statement because its logging out NaN for Rating_count

Comment: So the problematic line is the testStorage.Rating_count++ that isnt working. I tried testStorage.Rating_count = 2 and that works, but the increment wont work

Comment: Don't you think this should be testStorage1.Rating_count ? `  const testObject = { 
      Rating_count: testStorage1,
      Rating_date: new Date()
    };`  instead of just testStorage1?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I am such a ding dong. See the edited above testObject. The reason it was NaN because I was passing the whole asyncStorage object to key lol

Comment: Yes, the edit was what I meant. Still not working?

Comment: No it works now! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add .Rating_count to the testObject.
Originally I was passing the entire AsyncStorage object to the key Rating_count.
end original object

const testObject = {
Rating_count: testStorage1.Rating_count,
Rating_date: moment()
};